# How to write array object in plist in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist

In an app I have a `plist`:

```
root ---> dictionary
  cell ----> array
    item0 ---> string
    item1 ----> string
```

and so on.

In `tableView` which holds the data from this `plist` & tableview `navigation bar` holds an `add button`. When I clicked on it, it pushes  another view which holds a `text field` & a `button`. I want to store the text field's text into the plist in an array at the last object by clicking on the button.

Whenever I reload the tableview, the data is stored in the `plist` permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code....

```
-(void)dataFetching
{
NSMutableDictionary *categoryList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Give the file path"];
NSMutableArray *array =(NSMutableArray *) [categoryList valueForKey:@"write the array name here"];

/* hope u know how a table loads data from the array */

/*whenever add button is pressed on the table view cell, view would be shown with a textfield and a button, isn't it? */

/* by setting the delegate for textfield, using the textfieldDidEnterEditing: method capture the text from the textfield*/
// for example, 
NSString *testStr = @"test String"; //[textfield text];
//Now,

int lastItemIndex = [array count];
[array insertObject:testStr atIndex:lastItemIndex];
// and whenever you want you can save it on to the file like this

[categoryList writeToFile:@"Give the file path" atomically:YES];

[categoryList release];
}
```

hope this helps.....

Comment: scuse me if i reopen this post, i want to know how to load a mustabledictionary from file, update it and rewrite on file :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the methods

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

for NSDictionary and NSArray

and also

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```